# AJAX + JSON for simple login

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I am new to AJAX and JSON i'm looked tutorials for it but it seems that that dept is to much for me.

I decided to make a simple login to see how AJAX and JSON works but don't know how to start.
Some said that i need `library jars` for it and some said its just a `javasrcipt`

Here is my simple login jsp page

```
<body>
    <form action="LoginController" method="post">
        <!-- Login body -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="userName" >Username:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="password" >Password:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

How would i apply `JSON` + `AJAX` to it so it wouldn't refresh if the user doesn't enter a proper Username and Password

By the way here's my controller:

```
UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(); // instantiate DAO class to access dummy database

        String userName = request.getParameter( "userName" ); // get userName String from the Login.jsp
        String password = request.getParameter( "password" ); // get password String from the Login.jsp

        if( userDAO.authenticate( userName, password ) ) // validate userName and password
        {

            UserModel userModel = userDAO.getUserDetails( userName ); // get userModel that correspond to userName parameter

            request.getSession().setAttribute( "userName", userName ); // set SESSION REQUEST to be forward to MainPage.jsp
            request.setAttribute( "userDetails", userModel ); // set REQUEST to be forward to MainPage.jsp

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( "MainPage.jsp" );
            rd.forward( request, response ); // forward request to MainPage.jsp
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect( "Login.jsp" );
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a the data structure javascript objects are formatted in. If you are using jQuery the correct way to send a request via ajax would be to use either the $.ajax function or the $.post function in this case.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var action_script = $(this).closest('form').prop('action');
    $.post(action_script, {userName : $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="userName"]'), password: $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="password"]')}, function(returned_data){
        //this part executes once the server returns a successful response
    });
});
```

This binds a handler to the click event of the submit button which will stop a normal post from occuring which would result in a page refresh. The $.post() will then post the data userName and password to the server and will execute the success callback when the response is sent back.

`{userName : $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="userName"], password: $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="password"]')}` is an example of JSON. This is a simple JSON object with two attributes userName and password. It is a set of key value pairs and is such can be treated like an associative array.

When an AJAX request is made the response will not force a re render of a page so you will have to handle the resultant data in the callback method of the `$.post()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more information on how the .ajax method in jQuery works

Comment: Can i ask what do i need and how would i implement this code you posted?

Comment: If you have jQuery working already just include this code in the `$(document).ready` handler and it will work for the posting.

Comment: I don't have a `jQuery` and no idea to it. It seems like it's similar it `Javasript`?

Comment: One more question where would i implement `JQuery`? at the head tag?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. Read up on it at http://jquery.com/ add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` to your head to load it.